# Cardano's method returns incorrect answer for $x = u + v$

Tags: cubics

I'm trying to use [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) to solve this equation:
$$x^3+6x=20 \tag{1}$$

As described on Wikipedia, I let $x = u + v$ and expand in $(1)$:
$$(u+v)^3+6(u+v)=20$$
$$u^3 + v^3 + (3uv+6)(u+v)-20=0 \tag{2}$$

I then let $3uv + 6 = 0$ and substitute in $(2)$:
$$u^3 + v^3 - 20 = 0$$
$$u^3 + v^3 = 20 \tag{3}$$

I also express $uv$ as a product of cubics:
$$3uv + 6 = 0$$
$$uv = -2$$
$$u^3v^3 = -8$$
$$-4u^3v^3 = 32 \tag{4}$$

At this point, Wikipedia says "the combination of these two equations [$(3)$ and $(4)$] leads to a quadratic equation" which I think I can also be achieved by squaring $(3)$ and adding $(4)$ to both sides:
$$u^6 + 2u^3v^3 + v^6 = 400$$
$$u^6 - 2u^3v^3 + v^6 = 432$$
$$(u^3 - v^3)^2 = 432$$
$$u^3 - v^3 = \pm 12\sqrt{3} \tag{5}$$

I then get $u$ by adding $(3)$ and $(5)$:
$$2u^3 = 20 + 12\sqrt{3} \textrm{ or } 20 - 12\sqrt{3}$$
$$u = \sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}} \textrm{ or } \sqrt[3]{10 - 6\sqrt{3}}$$

and $v$ by subtracting $(3)$ and $(5)$:
$$2v^3 = 20 - 12\sqrt{3} \textrm{ or } 20 + 12\sqrt{3}$$
$$v = \sqrt[3]{10 - 6\sqrt{3}} \textrm{ or } \sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}}$$

I finally get $x$ by adding $u$ and $v$:
$$x = \sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}} + \sqrt[3]{10 - 6\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\textrm{ or } \sqrt[3]{10 - 6\sqrt{3}} + \sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\textrm{ or } 2\sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\textrm{ or } 2\sqrt[3]{10 - 6\sqrt{3}}$$

I know there's a real solution, so that only leaves $x = 2\sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}}$ which equals approximately $195$ instead of $20$ in the original equation. I can only find the correct real solution by using $x = u - v$ instead of $x = u + v$:

$$x = \sqrt[3]{10 + 6\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt[3]{6\sqrt{3} - 10}$$

So, am I misusing Cardano's method somehow?

Comment: Note that $10-6\sqrt{3}$ is negative, which is perfectly fine, we are taking the cube root not the square root. Not explicit in your post, but implicit "so that only leaves $\dots$" is the belief that the cube root of a negative number is problematic.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, that makes perfect sense but I was misled when verifying my answer with sage: `(-8)^(1/3)` returns a complex number whereas `RR(-8).cube_root()` returns a real number.

Comment: Note by the way that $\sqrt[3]{10+6\sqrt{3}}=1+\sqrt{3}$. You can verify this by cubing the right-hand side. Also, the cube root of $10-6\sqrt{3}$ is $1-\sqrt{3}$. Sum is $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the condition $u^3v^3=-8$. The correct solution is the first you enunciated.

That said, your way of solving the system of equations $\; \begin{cases}u^3+v^3=20\\u^3v^3=-8\end{cases}\;$ is over complicated.

Just use what any high-school student knows to solve the problem of finding two numbers the sum $s$ and product $p$ of which are given: they're roots of the quadratic equation (if any):
$$t^2-st+p=t^2-20t-8=0$$
The reduced discriminant is $\Delta'=100+8$, hence the roots 
$$u^3,v^3=10\pm\sqrt{108}=10\pm6\sqrt 3.$$
You must take *both roots*, because the problem involves the condition on the product is $8$ – i.e. it implies the qudratic equation, but is not equivalent to it. Thus
$$x=u+v=\sqrt[3]{10-6\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{10+6\sqrt 3}.$$

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @André Nicolas $10\pm6\sqrt 3=(1\pm\sqrt3)^3$, so that the root is equal to $2$.

Comment: Since $x^3+6 x-20=(x-2)(x^2+ 2 x +10)$ we must have $(10-6\sqrt 3)^{1/3}$ $+(10+6\sqrt 3)^{1/3}=2.$ See Andre Nicolas' comments.

Comment: Oh, yes. Didn't think of checking whether it simplified. My main point was to show the O.P. his conceptual error.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer. I just noticed that x=2 is a solution, and by factoring, the only real one.

Comment: @user254665: Yes, but using, say,, the *Rational roots theorem* doesn't answer the O.P.'s question. Further, even if you don't find an explicit root, considering the derivative shows there's only $1$ real root.

Comment: Agreed. I was just adding a footnote. I see you added an edit.